Chrome and Edge : Third party partitioning- How to share data now?
Since the browsers have implemented the storage partitioning, we have had issues were we share data with a word addin plugin in an iframe. The temporary work around that we have done right now is to disable the flag for Third party storage partitioning so that the access is still present.
Going forward what would be the best solution to get around this and still have access to the local storage?
From what I understand the solution could be document.requestStorageAccess(); but then as I understand this would prompt the user to provide access. Is this the recommended solution ? Or is there a better way to get around this?

As you know, browsers use third-party storage partitioning to improve user privacy. This is already a default behavior, but it is currently possible to disable this feature by disabling the "Third-party Storage Partitioning" flag.
In addition, according to my search, one solution is the "requestStorageAccess () method" you already know. It allows embedded third-party websites to request access to their previously stored data even if third-party storage partitioning is enabled, but as you know, this will prompt the user to provide access permissions. You can refer to this link:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/requestStorageAccess
Another solution is about CHIPS, you can refer to this link: https://github.com/privacycg/CHIPS
